# Are Hermitian operators hermitian in all spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

When I was learning quantum theory, I learned that Hamiltonian operators are hermitian in Hilbert space. But when I tried to write it in matrix form, i.e., when I wrote the $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ and the multiplicative operator $V(x)$ as a matrix for a vector space with basis vectors $x^0,x^1$ and so on, I found that the resulting matrix was not hermitian. But how can this be? They're both representing the same equation, so why is there such a difference? 
Sorry for the bad usage of terms, I'm not really a math major.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to typeset mathematical expressions. You can find a tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I think the problem is that the basis vectors $x^0,x^1$ and so on do not form an orthonormal basis.